# In Nodejs, Telegram API, messages.sendMultiMedia method is not working?

Tags: node.js, api, telegram

Here is a method that sends one media message to a channel and that works fine:
Link for official docs : https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMedia

```
public async sendMedia(channel_id:number, access_hash:string, message:string): Promise<any>{
        return await this.sendTelegram("messages.sendMedia", {
        peer : {
            _ : 'inputPeerChannel',
            channel_id,
            access_hash,
        },
        random_id: BigInt(new Date().getTime()),
        message: message,
        media:  {
            _ : "inputMediaPhotoExternal",
            url:"some image url",
        },
        });    
    }
```

But almost the same thing, it is for multiple medias.
Link for official docs : https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMultiMedia
Below the method.

```
public async sendMultiMedia(channel_id:number, access_hash:string, message:string): 
 Promise<any>{
        return await this.sendTelegram("messages.sendMultiMedia", {
        peer : {
            _ : 'inputPeerChannel',
            channel_id,
            access_hash,
        },
        multi_media:[
            {
                _ : "inputSingleMedia",
                random_id: BigInt(new Date().getTime()),
                message,
                media : { 
                    _ : "inputMediaContact",
                    url:"some image url",
                }
            }
    ]
        });    
    }
```

The first method is working fine, but the second one is not working.
Telegram Api responses INVALID_MEDIA,( both media in put is the same )

Could someone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As for now, Telegram does not support sending multiple media by URL, doing so will cause an `INVALID_MEDIA` error.

However, you may use `uploadMedia` to upload each photo respectively (by URL), get a list of `inputMedia`, and send them using `sendMultimedia`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try